# Python regex to find blocks between tags that contains a word

Tags: python, regex

I have this text:

```
text = '''
    <TABLE>
        FINDME
        aaaa
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        eeee
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        FINDME
        iiii
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        oooo
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE>
        FINDME
        uuuu
    </TABLE>
'''
```

How can I find the contents between  tags if the the word "FINDME" is in them? I would like to obtain an array of all matches.

Expected output would be (omitting blanks):

```
>> ['FINDME\naaaa', 'FINDME\niiii', 'FINDME\nuuuu']
```

This is what I have so far:

```
pattern = re.compile("<TABLE>(.*FINDME.*)</TABLE>",re.DOTALL)
matches = re.findall(pattern, text)
```

Which returns:

```
>> ['\n        FINDME\n        aaaa\n    </TABLE>\n        eeee\n    <TABLE>\n        FINDME\n        iiii\n    </TABLE>\n        oooo\n    <TABLE>\n    <TABLE>\n        FINDME\n        uuuu\n    ']
```

It does not work as expected as it is greedy and puts everything in the same match.

I have also tried:

```
pattern = re.compile("<TABLE>(.*?)</TABLE>",re.DOTALL)
matches = re.findall(pattern, text)
```

This returns:

```
>> ['\n        FINDME\n        aaaa\n    ',
 '\n        eeee\n    ',
 '\n        FINDME\n        iiii\n    ',
 '\n        oooo\n    ',
 '\n        FINDME\n        uuuu\n    ']
```

It is non greedy but does not filter out matches without FINDME

I have also tried a combination of both trying to make it non greedy but clearly I am doing something wrong:

```
pattern = re.compile("<TABLE>(.*FINDME.*)</TABLE>?",re.DOTALL)
matches = re.findall(pattern, text)
```

But it behaves as the first one.

Would you please help me with this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML, use Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Thanks. You are completely right. I am just trying to learn regex and this is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that basically the greedy operator `.*` eats `FINDME` in `r".*FINDME"` and therefore `FINDME` gets completely ignored.

This is the correct pattern that you're looking for

```
pattern = re.compile(r"<TABLE>[\n\s]+FINDME.*?</TABLE>?")
```

**Edit1**: `[\n\s]+` means `match any combination of newline \n or whitespace \s`. You also don't need `?` after `</TABLE>` if your HTML code is valid.

**Edit2**: Maybe another (possibly better) explanation is that since you have multiple `FINDME` in the string, `.*FINDME` does aggressively look for as many `FINDME`s as possible, and then matches everything until it finds the last `FINDME`. On the other hand, `FINDME.*` matches the first `FINDME` and then continues to match everything else (i.e. whatever that both `.*` and `re.DOTALL` allow).

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for the solution and for the explanation!